# RegExp to get all URLs in string except link hrefs

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to form a `RegExp` to replace all URLs in a string with link elements except URLs which already are `href` attribute of existing links.

This Regexp converts all URLs - including `href`s - to new anchor element:

```
/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig
```

which is not desired. [Codepen](http://codepen.io/alihaghighatkhah/pen/vOdLRe).

How can I replace only URLs that are not `href` of existing link elements?

*Note:*
*According to many documents Regex and RegExp are both identical and valid.*
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40a0cc3e(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: don't parse HTML like this with regexp, parse it with a DOM and then iterate and collect.

Comment: @ali link you gave is working fine. And pls use SO ide for writing js codes.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I have 2 links is my HTML code whose href is converted to link elements after parsing with RegExp : a link element as the value of href attribute of another link element. which is not correct obviously.

Comment: @dandavis may you please explain more?

Comment: @AvinashRaj it's good to have the question and code in one place, but I think because of the bad UX design of the SO ide, the result reduces the readability of the question. doesn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure you are not inside the `<a>` tag.

You can use the `(?![^<>]*>(?:(?!<\/?a\b).)*<\/a>)` lookahead to do this (it will make sure there is no closing angle bracket of the opening tag, and no `</a>` tag will follow).

```
var urlToLinkExp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])(?![^<>]*>(?:(?!<\/?a\b).)*<\/a>)/ig;
                                                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Code:

```js
var urlToLinkExp = /(\b(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])(?![^<>]*>(?:(?!<\/?a\b).)*<\/a>)/ig;


var el = document.getElementById('target');
el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(urlToLinkExp,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>");
```

```css
p
{
  font-family: tahoma;
}
a
{
  background: #C7DBFC;
  color: #333;
  padding: 2px 4px;
}
```

```html
<p id="target">
www.demo.com http://example.com/ is a url 

https://example.com/foo.html?q=bar zxv xc zcv <a href="http://google.com" sadf >the href of this link is corrupted</a> dfg fgxc zcv <a href='http://google.com' sadf >the href of this link is <strong>corrupted</strong></a>
<p>
```

[image]

Comment: I used this RegExp, unfortunately it doesn't work correctly with multiple space-separated URLs. I tried to fix it but I'm not good in RegExps. how to fix it?

Comment: I have just checked, and it looks like it's working. Could you provide a sample text?